# Configure multiple monitors with a desktop independend gui

Tags: gnome, software-rec, window-manager, xmonad

Since my upgrade from ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 `gnome-control-center display` is broken. It could not get any screen information. According to this bug report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=755048 the reason seams to be that the screen handling code moved from gnome-settings-daemon to gnome-shell (for wayland support's sake) which means the control center display settings won't work with other WMs anymore.

Usually I use `gnome-control-center display` for my xmonad setup to configure monitors. Is there any alternative tool for gnome-control-center display` which works with xmonad and other window managers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found [`arandr`](http://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/). Here is a screenshot:

[image]